# How to set limit to the number of concurrent request in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I got this servlet which return a pdf file to the client web browser.
We do not want to risk any chance that when the number of request is too much, the server is paralyzed.

We would like to make an application level (program) way to set a limit in the number of concurrent request, and return a error message to the browser when the limit is reached. We need to do it in applicantion level because we have different servlet container in development level(tomcat) and production level(websphere).

I must emphasize that I want to control the maximum number of request instead of session. A user can send multiple request over the server with the same session.

Any idea?
I've thought about using a static counter to keep track of the number of request, but it would raise a problem of race condition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631981/limiting-number-of-requests-to-a-servlet looks like it answers the question - what server are you using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd suggest writing a simple servlet `Filter`. Configure it in your `web.xml` to apply to the path that you want to limit the number of concurrent requests. The code would look something like this:

```
public class LimitFilter implements Filter {
    private int limit = 5;
    private int count;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            boolean ok;
            synchronized (lock) {
                ok = count++ < limit;
            }
            if (ok) {
                // let the request through and process as usual
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                // handle limit case, e.g. return status code 429 (Too Many Requests)
                // see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3
            }
        } finally {
            synchronized (lock) {
                count--;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you could just put this logic into your `HttpServlet`. It's just a bit cleaner and more reusable as a `Filter`. You might want to make the limit configurable through the `web.xml` rather than hard coding it.

**Ref.:**
Check definition of [HTTP status code 429](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3).

Comment: @WhiteFang34, can you post your previous solution? I would like to check out what Ralph said. I would really prefer using a simple counter. The small race condition can be omit, I don't care if someone need to wait...

Comment: @gunbuster363: it's in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5563656/revisions). The latest is still a simple counter though.

Comment: I am afraid the synchronize() method will make itself the bottleneck of the program.

Comment: @gunbuster363: the synchronize is not around the whole request (that definitely wouldn't work, it'd limit it to one concurrent). It's only around the check to see if the limit has been reached. It's very short and very minimal overhead. I've used a much more complicated version of this for many years and it works great. Give it a try, just have a servlet sleep for 10 seconds and make a bunch of requests. Only 5 (or your limit) will run concurrently.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 hey folk.. i tried this and this is working fine. I would like to ask you that if suppose i would like to set that if no of concurrent request is reaching above 5000; then it should return 429 status code. Moreover limit is changed to 5000 is it enough to check it.

Comment: Can try http://rationalcoding.blogspot.in/2014/03/concurrent-requests-limiter.html if we use spring. But if we use Load balancer, then need to change from ConcurrentHashMap to Some sort of storage like Redis

Answer (score 3):

You can use RateLimiter. See [this](https://ivanursul.com/how-to-limit-number-of-requests)  article for explanation.

Comment: Just remove the / character from the end . Try https://ivanursul.com/how-to-limit-number-of-requests this.

Answer (score 2):

> I've thought about using a static counter to keep track of the number of request, but it would raise a problem of race condition.

If you use a AtomicInteger for the counter, you will not have the problem of race conditions.

An other way would be using the [Java Executor Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) (comes with Java 1.5). There you are able to limit the number of running threads, and block new once until there is a new free thread.

But I think the counter would work and be the easyest solution.

*Attention: put the counter relese in a finally block!*

```
//psydo code
final AtomicInteger counter;
...
while(true) {
  int v = counter.getValue()
  if (v > max) return FAILURE;
  if(counter.compareAndSet(v, v+1)) break;  
}
try{
  doStuff();
} finally{
  counter.decrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the `counter` be `volatile`?

Comment: @asgs The counter should been `final` because it is not intended to been reassigned, then no volatile is needed

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look on [Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

> Semaphores are often used to restrict the number of threads than can access some (physical or logical) resource.

Or even better try to figure it out with the server settings. That would of course be server-dependant.

Comment: Sempahores will not work for this, because the will block the request, if the semaphore is below 0. But the requirement was to send a error message in this case.

Comment: @Ralph: It would work with `tryAcquire()`, but it's overkill.

Comment: I don't think it is "overkill" to use a well-tested piece of library software (`Semaphore`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving static files, it's unlikely that the server will crash. The bottleneck would be the network throughput, and it degrades gracefully - when more requests come in, each still get served, just a little bit slower.

If you set a hard limit on total requests, remember to set a limit on requests per IP. Otherwise, it's easy for one bad guy to issue N requests, deliberately read the responses very slowly, and totally clog your service. This works even if he's on a dialup and your server network has a vast throughput.

Comment: This is just a preventive measure. "If" the request is capable of paralyzing the network, it is our responsibility to limit the number of incoming request. Do you have any idea?