# Unlimited session object cause RAM be full

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am learning about the Java EE HttpSession (in Tomcat). It says that when we close the browser, the cookie `JSessionID=12345` will be destroyed (but on the server side, a session object still retain until its lifespan ends).

Let's say we set the session lifespan to be one hour. There is a kind of scenario that a user repeats the following action:

1. access servlet (and this servlet calls `getSession()`)
2. close browser (or clear cookie).

So this repetition will cause a lot of useless session objects to be created, and they will only be destroyed after their lifespan ends.

In this case, some 'hacker' will be able to write a program to exploit our server (keep on creating session objects until we run out of RAM). Will this scenario be possible in a real environment? Does Java EE do anything to prevent this?

Comment: Well, you can write a (Servlet) `Filter` for this purpose as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563442/how-to-set-limit-to-the-number-of-concurrent-request-in-servlet, but I admit it may not be a good idea to limit the amount of parallel users. But you can deny parallel access from the same IP. DDoS will be still threat though.

Comment: Or you can modify the http connector in Tomcat's `server.xml` and add `maxThreads=n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is definitively a real life scenario. I know cases where search engines killed web sites by crawling the site, because they created a new huge session on each request.

I guess there are only two ways to handle this:

- Keep the session lifetime as short as possible.
- Prevent the use of the session to store huge objects.

I generally prefer the latter one. IMHO there are very few cases where you REALLY need to store huge objects in the session.

This is also what you will lean in books like [Release it](http://pragprog.com/book/mnee/release-it) by Michael T. Nygard (very good book by the way).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a public site, you probably don't need sessions and can configure your webapp not to create them.

If you have a login-required site, you need to plan this accordingly: plan for capacity, only create session for private pages, put as less objects into session as possible, keep session timeout low, etc.

Java EE does not provide out-of-the-box protection against DDOS in the same way Apache HTTP server does not protect against someone creating billion requests per second (and preventing other users accessing the site), but suggests the ways to be able to minimize the impact.